# Comparing two lists of objects with lists of strings and ensuring no overlap

Tags: vb.net, list, compare

I have an object that contains multiple lists.

```
Public Class aObject
    Public Property title
    Public Property aList As List(Of String)
    Public Property bList As List(Of String)
    Public Property cList As List(Of String)
    Public Property dList As List(Of String)
End Class
```

I have another object where I store all the aObjects.

```
Public Class bObject
 Private _LocalCollection As List(Of aObject)
 Private _RemoteCollection As List(Of aObject)
End Class
```

Each list in aObject is a different setting. If I add a new setting, I want to be able to make sure that all the combinations never cross. So, if I was storing letters in aList and numbers in bList and had an object with {1,6,7} and {a,d,z}, I would not want to add another setting with lists {2,6,8} and {a,f,g}. However, I would want to add the lists {1,6,7} and {b,c,f}. All four lists are the same way. I need to check the combination of the four. I can use a recursive algorithm and check all the values, but I was wondering if there was some other way.

I used the following suggested answer and implemented it:

```
Public Function checkDuplicates(ByVal strChampions As List(Of String), ByVal strSummonerSpells As List(Of String), ByVal strModes As List(Of String), ByVal strMaps As List(Of String)) As Boolean
    Dim booDuplicates As Boolean = False
    For Each setting In _LocalSettings
        Dim l1 = setting.champions.Intersect(strChampions)
        If l1.Count() > 0 Then
            Dim l2 = setting.summonerspells.Intersect(strSummonerSpells)
            If l2.Count() > 0 Then
                Dim l3 = setting.modes.Intersect(strModes)
                If l3.Count() > 0 Then
                    Dim l4 = setting.maps.Intersect(strMaps)
                    If l4.Count() > 0 Then
                        booDuplicates = booDuplicates Or True
' I am going to create the duplicate settings here to know where to overwrite.
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return booDuplicates
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you check the intersection of the lists to see if there are common elements?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx

> The intersection of two sets A and B is defined as the set that contains all the elements of A that also appear in B, but no other elements.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim a As New List(Of String) From {"1", "6", "7"}
    Dim b As New List(Of String) From {"a", "d", "z"}
    Dim c As New List(Of String) From {"2", "6", "8"}

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("a intersects b: {0}", a.Intersect(b).Count > 0))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("a intersects c: {0}", a.Intersect(c).Count > 0))
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("b intersects c: {0}", b.Intersect(c).Count > 0))

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Outputs:

```
a intersects b: False
a intersects c: True
b intersects c: False
```

Comment: Sounds great. I have to reiterate through all the objects, but I realized it's actually important what intersects as well. That way, I can overwrite or not. Now, I just have to figure out how to overwrite the objects. Thank you.